# Printing out values in loops, values is not being printed out than a certain number

Tags: c++, loops

I want to make a program that Multiplies every other digit by 2, starting with the number’s second-to-last digit, and then add those products’ digits together. For example, lets take an integer 4003600000000014

Okay, let’s multiply each of the underlined digits by 2:

1•2 + 0•2 + 0•2 + 0•2 + 0•2 + 6•2 + 0•2 + 4•2

That gives us:

2 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 12 + 0 + 8

Now let’s add those products’ digits (i.e., not the products themselves) together:

2 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 2 + 0 + 8 = 13.
what's wrong with my program

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    float number=0,duplicate=0;
    int mod=0;
    cin>>number;
    duplicate=number;  
    int sum1 =0;           
    while(duplicate>0)
    {
        duplicate=duplicate/10;
        mod =duplicate%10;      
        sum1 =(mod*2)+sum1;
        duplicate=duplicate/10;
        
    }
    cout<<sum1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is using the wrong data type. First, floating-point arithmetic leads to rounding errors. Second, `float` can only hold about 7 significant decimal places, and even `double` is not large enough for your example (4003600000000014).

What you should use instead is `std::vector<int>` and store individual digits of the input in the vector elements.

Comment: Or use a library like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) that deals in Numbers Of Unusual Size.